# Autofs trying to mount ZFS filesystems and failing

Tags: mount, zfs, solaris

I created four filesystems using zfs on my T2000 running Solaris 11.3.  Two automatically mount on boot (as they should) but two fail with the error message from autofs that the mount points are not empty.  (This causes all sorts of services to fail afterwards.)

I think that I accidentally added the failing mounts to autofs but I am unable to correct this, that is, removing them from being mounted by autofs.  They are not in /etc/vfstab.

How do I remove the failing filesystems from autofs?

Comment: `autofs` uses `/etc/auto.master` - does that help?

Comment: How new is your `zfs --version`? I do not know autofs but your problem reminds me of an issue I had recently on ubuntu where there was a race condition at boot, causing `/tmp` (others reported `/var`) as well to actually be created as a directory before being mounted as a dataset. An update of zfs fixed that issue for me. Might be related, might be completely a different issue.

Comment: @JaromandaX It would be `/etc/auto_master` on Solaris.  But yeah, that's where to start.  If the automounted file systems aren't listed in `/etc/auto_master`, additional files are included by lines like `/home           auto_home       -browse`.  That line means directories under `/home` are mounted by the autofs entries in `/etc/auto_home`.  Other potential entries would be `/net            -hosts          -nosuid,browse`, which means directories under `/net` are mapped to host entries in `/etc/hosts`. And a simple `zfs list` command as root should show you all ZFS filesystems with mountpoint